# Confused about single strand Fiber media converter or duplex media converter?

Tags: fiber, duplex, media-conversion

As per Title you may understand my question. I have read many articles about WDM technology as well as Tx/Rx on separate optical fiber. Here my question is which is better in real environment?

Any pros and cons about WDM fiber networking? We are using RING topology with DUPLEX fiber networking via Mini-GBIC modules on L2 switches.

I am thinking to go with WDM technology to making separate network for CCTV camera and DATA on separate single strand fiber.

Help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may be interested in [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/34306/8499) and answers for a different way to use a single fiber for full-duplex communication.

Comment: Very appreciating your reply. I read that thread and it also helpful to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no difference performance wise. The reason we use WDM converters is the fact, that it only uses 1 single fiber connection and thereby we save a lot of fiber infrastructure.

The WDM optic sends different wave lengths through the single fiber so that the Tx and Rx doesn't collide. We use WDM optics on all our equipment for speeds from 1 Gbit up to 100 Gbit currently and we've never had any problems.

Please note that the Cisco QSFP-100G-CWDM4-S uses a standard pair of G.652 Single-Mode Fiber (SMF) with duplex LC connectors. The 100 Gigabit Ethernet signal is carried over four wavelengths. Multiplexing and demultiplexing of the four wavelengths are managed within the device.

Comment: Your words really helpful to understand better and it clear my confusion about the same. Thanks a lot for your answer.